# JDBC Realm Form Authentication Login Failed

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-4, jdbcrealm

I tried to create a JDBC Realm and Form Base Authentication, I was able to successfully follow the instructions in JavaEE tutorial but I always receive a login failed message.

Can someone point me to the right direction ? I know that I just missed something in the tutorial.

I already paste mysql's .jar at domain/domain1/lib

**Realm:**

```
Realm Name: my_realm
Class Name:
com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm
JAAS Context: jdbcRealm
JNDI: my_jndi
User Table: sample_db.app_users
User Name Column: username
Password Column:  password
Group Table:  sample_db.roles
Group Name Column: role_name
Password Encryption Algorithm: 1234
Digest Algorithm: SHA-512 // **EDIT: this is SHA-256**
Encoding: Base64
```

**web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>protected-pages</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>protected-pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>authenticatedUser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>my_realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/index.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>authenticatedUser</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**glassfish-web.xml**

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>authenticatedUser</role-name>
    <group-name>authenticatedUser</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

**LoginController.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {
    public void login() {
        try {
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();

            request.login(this.getUsername(), null); 

            // redirect to home page
            fc.getExternalContext().redirect("faces/home.xhtml");

        } catch(ServletException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit: (Additional Info)**
The password field data type is blob and right now its value is NULL, just for testing purposed. :)

**Edit:**
Change Digest Algorithm to `SHA-256`. I change password field data type to varchar but still I receive login failed message.

---

**Update:**
I updated the password field with the encrypted password.

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;
MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
md.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] passwordDigest = md.digest();
System.out.println(Base64.encode(passwordDigest));
```

Here is the updated login method

```
public void login() {
            try {
                FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();

                request.login(this.getUsername(), this.getPassword()); 

                // redirect to home page
                fc.getExternalContext().redirect("faces/home.xhtml");

            } catch(ServletException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

I tried to pass encrypted and NOT encrypted password but same output, login failed.

Thanks,
Bell

Comment: Why you are trying to login with a `null` password - `request.login(this.getUsername(), null); `? Besides, since you set the `Digest Algorithm` to `SHA-512`, you will need to store a list of passwords into the database according to that encryption (you do not need the BLOB datatype for storing passwords).

Comment: Hello tiny, thanks for your response, I set null password on request.login method because the value of user_password field was also null. With the Digest Algorithm, that was a mistake, it was SHA-256

Comment: I do not think that you are allowed to leave a password field blank. I never tried with a `null` password simply because it is not needed.

Comment: I updated the `user_password` with the encrypted value, please see the last update I posted. Also, I change request.login to `request.login(this.getUsername(), this.getPassword());`, but still I got `login failed` message.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of changes in jdbcRealm I found out that I did not deleted the file-realm that I created. I think that it was looking at the `file-realm`, though I indicated `my_realm` in `web.xml`.

Here is the latest realm settings.

```
Realm Name: my_realm
Class Name:
com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm
JAAS Context: jdbcRealm
JNDI: my_jndi
User Table: sample_db.app_users
User Name Column: username
Password Column:  password
Group Table:  sample_db.roles
Group Name Column: role_name
Password Encryption Algorithm: SHA-256
Digest Algorithm: SHA-256
Encoding: Base64
Char: UTF-8
```

Thanks,
Bell

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problems, which I could solve only by switching from Base64-Encoding to Hex-Encoding. Most probably the Base64-computation in Glassfish is broken.